# Loading android library

Tags: android, android-library, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have a library loaded like this:

```
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("myLibrary");
  }
```

This works fine on most devices.  On one device, however, it causes a crash with this stacktrace:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar", zip file "/vendor/overlay/myBuild.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "myLibrary.so"
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)
 at com.sony.foo.bar.<clinit>(myClass.java:20)
```

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27186726/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-dalvik-system-pathclassloader) prompted me to try adding a copy of myLibrary to a new `armeabi-v7` folder, where the original library was in a folder named `armeabi`. This fixed the crash.

I am trying to make sense out of this.  Does this mean the crashing phone has a different CPU?  A CPU-identifier app identifies it as having the same type (maker, model) as the others. Even supposing the crashing phone is `armeabi-v7`, the most upvoted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249501/armeabi-and-armeabi-v7a-folder) and the accepted answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12219202/difference-between-armeabi-and-armeabi-v7a) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080525/why-use-armeabi-v7a-code-over-armeabi-code) make it sound like an `armeabi-v7` phone should be able to use the library in the `armeabi` folder.  Is this not the case?

Lastly, is there some better approach to this fix so that I don't have two identical copies of the same library in the apk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be caused by having another version of the app installed on the phone in /system/priv-app. Removing that one prevented the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there is no such name `armeabi-v7` in Android, the correct name is `armeabi-v7a`.

The libraries under `armeabi-v7a` and `armeabi` is not identical actually. If you add more values to `APP_ABI` in the file `Application.mk` as following

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a mips x86
```

After `ndk-build`, there are four types of libraries will be generated in the folder `libs/armeabi`, `libs/armeabi-v7a`, `libs/x86`, `libs/mips`. By comparing the files between in `libs/armeabi` and `libs/armeabi-v7a`, you will see they are not identical. So far, i can't tell their differences. These two libraries are slightly different in size, so i think there are no big differences between them.

In order to make your app widely supported on most of the Android devices, you better add `armeabi-v7a` support and keep `armeabi-v7a` directory.

If you are sure what you are doing, only keep `armeabi`. Then, you can put your library under `assets` directory, when your app start and run, you should read your library from `assets` and load with `System.load()` manually other than relying on framework package manager system to inflate your library to your app's data directory when you app get installed.